# Java: Graphics2D - JPopupMenu - Color Changing

Tags: java, graphics2d

I’m writing a simple graphics editor, thus far I can draw some figures, move and enlarge them. I’m trying to allow user to change color of figure. After I right click in a shape, there appears a popup menu with colors to choose. But no matter what I do - the shape’s color doesn’t change. :/ I hope to get help, I spent a of of time on it but no idea how to solve it. :/

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class PaintPanel extends JPanel implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener, MouseWheelListener
{
    public RadioMenu radio = new RadioMenu();
    private ArrayList <Point2D.Double> points = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList <Shape> figures = new ArrayList<>();

    private Color mainColor = Color.blue;
    private Color bgColor = Color.white;
    private Color special = Color.red;
    private double scrollSpeed = 5;
    private int pointsize = 4;
    private int near = 15;

    private int index;
    private ColorMenu colorMenu = new ColorMenu();

    public PaintPanel()
    {
        super();
        addMouseListener(this);
        addMouseMotionListener(this);
        addMouseWheelListener(this);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        setBackground(bgColor);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        drawGraphics(g2d);
    }

    private void drawGraphics(Graphics2D g2d)
    {
        int i = 0;
        for (Shape s : figures)
        {

            g2d.setColor(mainColor);
            if (s instanceof MyEllipse2D)
            {
                g2d.setColor(((MyEllipse2D) s).color);
                System.out.println(g2d.getColor());
            }
            else if (s instanceof MyRectangle2D)
            {
                g2d.setColor(((MyRectangle2D) s).color);
                System.out.println(g2d.getColor());
            }
            else if (s instanceof MyPolygon2D)
            {
                g2d.setColor(((MyPolygon2D) s).color);
                System.out.println(g2d.getColor());
            }

            if (g2d.getColor() != bgColor)
            {
                g2d.setColor(mainColor);
            } else
            {
                g2d.setColor(mainColor);
                g2d.draw(s);
            }


            ++i;
        }

            i = 0;
            for (Point2D.Double p : points)
            {
                if (i == 0)
                {
                    g2d.setColor(special);
                    g2d.fillOval((int) p.getX(), (int) p.getY(), pointsize, pointsize);
                    g2d.setColor(mainColor);
                } else
                {
                    g2d.fillOval((int) p.getX(), (int) p.getY(), pointsize, pointsize);
                }
                ++i;
            }
        }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
    {
        if(e.getButton()==MouseEvent.BUTTON1)
            switch (radio.getChoice())
            {
                case "Okrag":
                    points.clear();
                    points.add(new Point2D.Double(e.getX(),e.getY()));
                    repaint();
                    break;

                case "Prostokat":
                    points.clear();
                    points.add(new Point2D.Double(e.getX(),e.getY()));
                    repaint();
                    break;

                case "Edycja":
                    index = isSelected(e);
                    break;
            }
        else if(e.getButton()==MouseEvent.BUTTON3 && radio.getChoice().equals("Edycja"))
            {
                index = isSelected(e);
                if(index >= 0)
                {
                    colorMenu.doPop(e);
                }

            }

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
    {
        if(e.getButton()==MouseEvent.BUTTON1)
            switch (radio.getChoice())
            {
                case "Okrag":
                    points.add(new Point2D.Double(e.getX(),e.getY()));
                    figures.add(new MyEllipse2D(points.get(0),points.get(1),bgColor));
                    points.clear();
                    break;

                case "Prostokat":
                    points.add(new Point2D.Double(e.getX(),e.getY()));
                    figures.add(new MyRectangle2D(points.get(0),points.get(1),bgColor));
                    points.clear();
                    break;

                case "Wielokat":
                    if(points.size() != 0 && points.get(0).distance(e.getX(),e.getY())<=near)
                    {
                        figures.add(new MyPolygon2D(points,bgColor));
                        points.clear();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        points.add(new Point2D.Double(e.getX(),e.getY()));
                    }
                    break;
                case "Edycja":
                    points.clear();
            }
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e)
    {
        if(index>=0 && radio.getChoice().equals("Edycja"))
        {
            if (figures.get(index) instanceof MyEllipse2D)
            {
                ((MyEllipse2D) figures.get(index)).move(new Point2D.Double(e.getX(),e.getY()));
            }
            else if (figures.get(index) instanceof MyRectangle2D)
            {
                ((MyRectangle2D) figures.get(index)).move(new Point2D.Double(e.getX(),e.getY()));
            }
            else if(figures.get(index) instanceof MyPolygon2D)
            {
                ((MyPolygon2D) figures.get(index)).move(new Point2D.Double(e.getX(),e.getY()));
            }
            repaint();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseWheelMoved(MouseWheelEvent e)
    {
        index = isSelected(e);
        if(radio.getChoice().equals("Edycja"))
        {
            if (index>=0)
            {
                if (figures.get(index) instanceof MyEllipse2D)
                {
                    ((MyEllipse2D) figures.get(index)).scale(e.getPreciseWheelRotation(), scrollSpeed);
                }
                else if (figures.get(index) instanceof MyRectangle2D)
                {
                    ((MyRectangle2D) figures.get(index)).scale(e.getPreciseWheelRotation(), scrollSpeed);
                }
                else if(figures.get(index) instanceof MyPolygon2D)
                {
                    ((MyPolygon2D) figures.get(index)).scale(e.getPreciseWheelRotation(), scrollSpeed);
                }
                repaint();
            }
        }
    }

    private int isSelected(MouseEvent e)
    {
        int i;
        for(i=figures.size()-1;i>=0;--i)
        {
            if(figures.get(i).contains(e.getPoint()))
            {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
    {
        index = isSelected(e);
        if(index >= 0 )
        {
            colorMenu.doPop(e);
            if(e.getButton()==MouseEvent.BUTTON3 && radio.getChoice().equals("Edycja"))
            {
                colorMenu.doPop(e);
                if(figures.get(index) instanceof MyEllipse2D)
                    ((MyEllipse2D) figures.get(index)).color = colorMenu.color;
                else if(figures.get(index) instanceof MyRectangle2D)
                    ((MyRectangle2D) figures.get(index)).color = colorMenu.color;
                else if(figures.get(index) instanceof MyPolygon2D)
                    ((MyPolygon2D) figures.get(index)).color = colorMenu.color;
                System.out.println(colorMenu.color);
                //colorMenu.color = bgColor;
            }
            repaint();
        }



    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e)
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e)
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e)
    {
    }
}
```

ColorMenu

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ColorMenu extends JPopupMenu implements ActionListener
{
    private ArrayList<JMenuItem> items = new ArrayList<JMenuItem>();
    private ArrayList<Color> colors = new ArrayList<Color>();

    public Color color;

    public ColorMenu()
    {
        super();
        colors.add(Color.black);
        colors.add(Color.blue);
        colors.add(Color.cyan);
        colors.add(Color.gray);
        colors.add(Color.green);
        colors.add(Color.magenta);
        colors.add(Color.orange);
        colors.add(Color.red);
        colors.add(Color.yellow);
        colors.add(Color.white);

        for (Color c : colors)
        {
            items.add(new JMenuItem(c.toString()));
        }

        for(JMenuItem i: items)
        {
            i.addActionListener(this);
            add(i);
        }

    }

    public void doPop(MouseEvent e)
    {
        show(e.getComponent(), e.getX(), e.getY());
    }


    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        Object source = e.getSource();
        int j=0;
        for(JMenuItem i: items)
        {
            if(i == source)
            {
                break;
            }
            ++j;
        }
        this.color = colors.get(j);
    }
}
```

MyRectangle2D

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;

public class MyRectangle2D extends Rectangle2D.Double implements Shape
{
    private Point2D.Double center;
    private double width,hight;
    public Color color;

    public MyRectangle2D()
    {}

    public MyRectangle2D(Point2D.Double p1, Point2D.Double p2, Color color)
    {
        super();
        this.color = color;

        double x1 = p1.getX();
        double y1 = p1.getY();
        double x2 = p2.getX();
        double y2 = p2.getY();

        if(x1<=x2 && y1>=y2)
        {
            width=x2-x1;
            hight=y1-y2;
            setRect(x1,y2,width,hight);
        }
        else if(x1<=x2 && y1<=y2)
        {
            width=x2-x1;
            hight=y2-y1;
            setRect(x1,y1,width,hight);
        }
        else if (x1>=x2 && y1<=y2)
        {
            width=x1-x2;
            hight=y2-y1;
            setRect(x2,y1,width,hight);
        }
        else if(x1>=x2 && y1>=y2)
        {
            width=x1-x2;
            hight=y1-y2;
            setRect(x2,y2,width,hight);
        }

        center = new Point2D.Double(x1 + (x2-x1)/2,y1+(y2-y1)/2);
    }

    public void scale(double amount, double scale)
    {
        double change = -1*amount*scale;
        width += change;
        hight += change;
        setRect(center.getX()-width/2,center.getY()-hight/2,width,hight);
    }

    public void move (Point2D.Double p)
    {
        center = p;
        setRect();
    }

    private void setRect()
    {
        setRect(center.getX()-width/2,center.getY()-hight/2,width,hight);
    }
}
```

MyPolygon2D

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MyPolygon2D extends Polygon implements Shape
{
    private ArrayList<MyVector> vectors = new ArrayList<>();
    private Point2D.Double center;
    private int size;
    public Color color;

    public MyPolygon2D()
    {}

    public MyPolygon2D(ArrayList<Point2D.Double> points, Color color)
    {
        super();

        this.color = color;

        size = points.size();

        for(int i=0; i<size;++i)
        {
            addPoint((int)points.get(i).getX(),(int)points.get(i).getY());
        }

        center();
        setVectors();
    }

    public void scale(double amount, double scale)
    {
        double change = -1*amount*scale;

        for (int i=0;i<size;++i)
        {
            vectors.get(i).x *= (100.0+change)/100.0;
            vectors.get(i).y *= (100.0+change)/100.0;

            Point2D.Double curr = new Point2D.Double(center.getX()+vectors.get(i).x,center.getY()+vectors.get(i).y);

            xpoints[i] = (int)curr.getX();
            ypoints[i] = (int)curr.getY();
        }
        invalidate();
    }

    public void move (Point2D.Double p)
    {
        MyVector change = new MyVector(center,p);
        center = p;

        for(int i=0;i<size;++i)
        {
            xpoints[i] += (int)change.x;
            ypoints[i] += (int)change.y;
        }
        invalidate();
    }

    public void setColor(Color color)
    {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public Color getColor()
    {
        return this.color;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean contains(Point p)
    {
        int maxx=0, maxy=0, minx=Integer.MAX_VALUE, miny=Integer.MAX_VALUE;

        for (int i=0;i<size;++i)
        {
            if(xpoints[i]>=maxx)
                maxx = xpoints[i];
            if(xpoints[i]<=minx)
                minx = xpoints[i];
            if(ypoints[i]>=maxy)
                maxy = ypoints[i];
            if(ypoints[i]<=miny)
                miny = ypoints[i];
        }
        if(p.getX() <= maxx && p.getX() >= minx && p.getY() <= maxy && p.getY() >=miny)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
    private void setVectors()
    {
        for(int i=0; i<size;++i)
        {
            vectors.add(new MyVector(center,new Point2D.Double(xpoints[i],ypoints[i])));
        }
    }

    private void center()
    {
        center = new Point2D.Double(getBounds2D().getX()+getBounds2D().getWidth()/2,getBounds2D().getY()+getBounds2D().getHeight()/2);
    }

    private class MyVector
    {
        public double x, y;

        public MyVector(Point2D.Double p1, Point2D.Double p2)
        {
            x=p2.getX()-p1.getX();
            y=p2.getY() - p1.getY();
        }
    }
}
```

MyEllipse2D

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;

public class MyEllipse2D extends Ellipse2D.Double implements Shape
{
    private double radius;
    private Point2D.Double center;
    public Color color;


    public MyEllipse2D(Point2D.Double p1, Point2D.Double p2, Color color)
    {
        super();
        this.color = color;
        center = p1;
        radius = (p1.distance(p2));
        setFrame();
    }

    public void scale(double amount, double scale)
    {
        double change = -1*amount*scale;
        radius += change;
        setFrame();
    }

    public void move (Point2D.Double p)
    {
        center = p;
        setFrame();
    }

    public void setColor(Color color)
    {
        this.color = color;
        System.out.println(this.color);
    }

    public Color getColor()
    {
        return this.color;
    }

    private void setFrame()
    {
        setFrame(center.getX()-radius,center.getY()-radius,2*radius,2*radius);
    }
}
```

RadioMenu

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class RadioMenu extends JPanel
{
    private int amount = 4;

    private JRadioButton[] options = new JRadioButton[amount];
    private ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();

    private String[] names = {"Okrag","Prostokat","Wielokat","Edycja"};


    private Font font = new Font("Times New Roman",Font.BOLD,16);

    public RadioMenu()
    {
        super();
        setLayout(new GridLayout(1,amount));

        for(int i=0;i<amount;++i)
        {
            if(i!=0)
                options[i] = new JRadioButton(names[i],false);
            else
                options[i] = new JRadioButton(names[i],true);

            group.add(options[i]);
            add(options[i]);
            options[i].setFont(font);
        }
    }

    public String getChoice()
    {
        for(int i=0; i<amount; ++i)
        {
            if(options[i].isSelected())
                return options[i].getText();
        }
        return "";
    }
}
```

Frame

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Frame extends JFrame
{
    private Dimension prefsize = new Dimension(800,600);
    private Dimension minSize = new Dimension(400,200);
    private Menu menu = new Menu();
    private PaintPanel panel = new PaintPanel();


    public Frame()
    {
        super();
        setVisible(true);
        setPreferredSize(prefsize);
        setMinimumSize(minSize);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        add(panel,BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JPanel upper = new JPanel();
        upper.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));
        upper.add(menu);
        upper.add(panel.radio);

        add(upper,BorderLayout.NORTH);
        pack();

    }
}
```

MyAplet

```
import javax.swing.*;

    public class MyAplet extends JApplet
    {
        public void init()
        {
            Frame main = new Frame();
        }
    }
```

Menu

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Menu extends JMenuBar
{
    private JMenu info;
    //private JMenuItem x;
    public Menu()
    {
        super();
        info = new JMenu("info");
        //info.add(x);
        add(info);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please reduce your code to a [mcve] otherwise I doubt anyone is going to check it...

Comment: You'd better off using [`MouseEvent#isPopupTrigger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseEvent.html#isPopupTrigger--) to determine if the `MouseEvent` should show the popup, but that would require to override `mousePressed`, `mouseReleased` and `mouseClicked` as the trigger is different for different OSs

Comment: A simpler solution would be to let the component handle it using [`JComponent#setComponentPopupMenu`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setComponentPopupMenu-javax.swing.JPopupMenu-)

Comment: Remember, just because you show the popup menu is made visible, doesn't mean that the color has been selected, so you can get the value from it until some other event occurs.  You could monitor the popup using a `PopupMenuListener` to detect when it's closed and check what was selected then

Answer (score 0):

First, you should be displaying a JPopupMenu in response to only one type of event.  You are currently calling `colorMenu.doPop(e)` in the mousePressed method and twice in the mouseClicked method.

To make sure you only display a JPopupMenu when you’re supposed to, you should use the [JPopupMenu.isPopupTrigger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JPopupMenu.html#isPopupTrigger-java.awt.event.MouseEvent-) method.  This way, the menu will be displayed on mousePress **or** mouseClick, but never both.  You do not want to display a JPopupMenu more than once in response to a single mouse action!

```
private int selectedIndex = -1;

// ...

@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
{
    selectedIndex = isSelected(e);
    if (colorMenu.isPopupTrigger(e)) {
        colorMenu.doPop(e);
    } else if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1) {

// ...

@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
{
    if (selectedIndex >= 0 && colorMenu.isPopupTrigger(e) && radio.getChoice().equals("Edycja"))
    {
        colorMenu.doPop(e);
```

The next problem is that you’re trying to read `colorMenu.color` before the user has made a color selection.  When you call `colorMenu.doPopup(e)`, the menu is displayed and the method returns immediately.  It does not wait for the user to make a selection and dismiss the menu.  Your code is trying to immediately make use of `colorMenu.color`, but it hasn’t been set yet.

The only way to know when the user has selected a color is with an ActionListener.  Your ColorMenu class has an ActionListener, but currently there is no way for the PaintPanel class to know when the ActionListener has been triggered.

You can give your ColorMenu class the capability of notifying listeners in other classes, using the inherited [listenerList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#listenerList) object:

```
public void addChangeListener(ChangeListener listener) {
    listenerList.add(ChangeListener.class, listener);
}

public void removeChangeListener(ChangeListener listener) {
    listenerList.remove(ChangeListener.class, listener);
}

public ChangeListener[] getChangeListeners() {
    return listenerList.getListeners(ChangeListener.class);
}

protected void fireChangeListeners() {
    ChangeEvent event = new ChangeEvent(this);
    for (ChangeListener listener : getChangeListeners()) {
        listener.stateChanged(event);
    }
}
```

(ChangeListener and ChangeEvent are in the javax.swing.event package.)

This allows other classes to listen for a user selection.  You want to change ColorMenu to actually notify those listeners:

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    // (other code) ...

    this.color = colors.get(j);
    fireChangeListeners();
}
```

Now, you can make PaintPanel listen for a user selection:

```
public PaintPanel()
{
    super();
    addMouseListener(this);
    addMouseMotionListener(this);
    addMouseWheelListener(this);
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    setBackground(bgColor);

    colorMenu.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent event) {
            if (selectedIndex >= 0)
            {
                Shape figure = figures.get(selectedIndex);
                if (figure instanceof MyEllipse2D)
                    ((MyEllipse2D) figure).color = colorMenu.color;
                else if (figure instanceof MyRectangle2D)
                    ((MyRectangle2D) figure).color = colorMenu.color;
                else if (figure instanceof MyPolygon2D)
                    ((MyPolygon2D) figure).color = colorMenu.color;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

You should remove that color changing code from `mouseClicked`, as it will never be valid to call it there, since the user hasn’t selected a color yet:

```
@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
{
    if (selectedIndex >= 0 && colorMenu.isPopupTrigger(e) && radio.getChoice().equals("Edycja"))
    {
        colorMenu.doPop(e);
        // Nothing else to do here, since the user has not selected a color yet.
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd use `JComponent#setComponentPopupMenu`, then the component takes care of all of it and you don't need to monitor 3 mouse events :P

Comment: @MadProgrammer What about the fact that the popup menu is only displayed when performing the popup trigger inside a previously added shape?

Comment: Disable the menu items 

Comment: Thanks for response but i have question - 
`public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent event) {
            index = isSelected(e);`
how i get MouseEvent e in this method ?

Comment: The selected index should be determined once, in mousePressed.  I’ve updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The basic problem is, you need to know when the color is selected from the menu.  The solution to the problem can be achieved in a number of different ways.

You could continue to use a `MouseListener` to monitor the `mousePressed`, `mouseReleased` and `mouseClicked` events, but you should be making using of the `MouseEvent#isPopupTrigger` property to determine when the popup should be displayed, as the triggers are different for different platforms.

Another solution would be to use `JComponent#setComponentPopupMenu` all the component to take care of the action itself.  This, however, would require a slight change in design.

This approach places the onus back onto the component, rather then been separated into a different class, like you have the `ColorMenu` right now.

To start with, we need to know the selected shape, so, to the `PaintPanel`, we need to add a new property

```
private Shape selectedShape;
```

All this does is determines which shape was selected by the user.

Next we need someway to update the shape color.  This can be achieved by simply adding a new method to the `paintPanel` method, which is called when the color is to be changed.

```
public void setShapeColor(Color color) {
    //...
}
```

Next, we take advantage of the `Action` API and create a simple `ColorAction`.

This is self contained unit of work, which contains the information need to display it on a menu (or button) and which determines the actions to take when triggered.

```
public class ColorAction extends AbstractAction {

    private Color color;

    public ColorAction(String name, Color color) {
        super(name);
        this.color = color;
    }

    public Color getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return getSelectedShape() != null;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        setShapeColor(color);
    }

}
```

In this case, this simple inner class to `PaintPanel` will call `setShapeColor` when triggered.

"But wait", I hear you call, "The colors can only be selected when a shape is selected!" Ah, we can control the `Action` through the `isEnabled` method, which will only return true when a shape is actually selected.

This might seem somewhat counterintuitive, but by not displaying a popup menu when nothing is displayed, it causes the user to think that no popup menu will be displayed ever, at least this way, we can display a popup menu with it's options disabled.

The next trick is trying to determine what is selected. Unfortunately, during my testing, the OS consumed the `mousePressed` event, which would have been most useful to make this determination, however, not all is lost.

The `JComponent` will call `getPopupLocation` just before the popup is made visible, passing in the `MouseEvent` which triggered it, we can take advantage of this to determine which shape would be selected

```
@Override
public Point getPopupLocation(MouseEvent event) {
    selectedShape = null;
    for (int i = figures.size() - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
        if (figures.get(i).contains(event.getPoint())) {
            selectedShape = figures.get(i);
        }
    }
    return super.getPopupLocation(event);
}
```

For a more complete example...

```
public class PaintPanel extends JPanel implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener, MouseWheelListener {

    private ArrayList<Point2D.Double> points = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<Shape> figures = new ArrayList<>();

    private Shape selectedShape;

    private Color mainColor = Color.blue;
    private Color bgColor = Color.white;
    private Color special = Color.red;
    private double scrollSpeed = 5;
    private int pointsize = 4;
    private int near = 15;

    private int index;

    public PaintPanel() {
        super();
        addMouseListener(this);
        addMouseMotionListener(this);
        addMouseWheelListener(this);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        setBackground(bgColor);
        setComponentPopupMenu(makePopupMenu());
    }

    protected JPopupMenu makePopupMenu() {
        JPopupMenu menu = new JPopupMenu();
        menu.add(new ColorAction("Black", Color.black));
        menu.add(new ColorAction("Blue", Color.blue));
        menu.add(new ColorAction("Cyan", Color.cyan));
        menu.add(new ColorAction("Grey", Color.gray));
        menu.add(new ColorAction("Green", Color.green));
        menu.add(new ColorAction("Megenta", Color.magenta));
        menu.add(new ColorAction("Orange", Color.orange));
        menu.add(new ColorAction("Red", Color.red));
        menu.add(new ColorAction("Yellow", Color.yellow));
        menu.add(new ColorAction("White", Color.white));

        return menu;
    }

    public Shape getSelectedShape() {
        return selectedShape;
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(200, 200);
    }

    @Override
    public Point getPopupLocation(MouseEvent event) {
        selectedShape = null;
        for (int i = figures.size() - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
            if (figures.get(i).contains(event.getPoint())) {
                selectedShape = figures.get(i);
            }
        }
        return super.getPopupLocation(event);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        //...
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        //...
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        //...
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        //...
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        //...
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        //...
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
        //...
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseWheelMoved(MouseWheelEvent e) {
        //...
    }

    public void setShapeColor(Color color) {
        //...
    }

    public class ColorAction extends AbstractAction {

        private Color color;

        public ColorAction(String name, Color color) {
            super(name);
            this.color = color;
        }

        public Color getColor() {
            return color;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isEnabled() {
            return getSelectedShape() != null;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            setShapeColor(color);
        }

    }

}
```

There are a couple of other ways you might achieve this, but I'd be using these basic principles are the cornerstone of the design.

For example, you could have a "color model" which get's passed to the popup menu class, which would be updated when a color is selected

Comment: I tried to implement this solution but i have error in
`menu.addPopupMenuListener(this);`
`Error:(327, 35) java: incompatible types: PaintPanel cannot be converted to javax.swing.event.PopupMenuListener`

Comment: You can remove that line, it was a left over from testing

Comment: I removed that line and options are always disabled